# Trigger jquery coda slider from another page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, coda

Hy.
So I'm working on a Wordpress project and need some help. Basically I display all my posts on category pages and everything works fine. But now what I would like to do is: When the user clicks on the post thumbnail on the first page it will take him to the category page where the coda slider is automatically triggered to scroll the right content in place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Coda Slider](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/#2) appears to work as expected: clicking one of the tabs adjusts the URL with #element-id at the end. The JS then takes over and animates to the appropriate element. As such, your link just needs to have the appropriate suffix - say, `<?php the_permalink ?>#scroll_to_this_element`.

In the example, the element names for the different tabs are `tab1`, `tab2`, etc, so your URL would be `<?php the_permalink ?>#tab5`.